# Pandas Melt Trouble in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file data frame that looks like the following:

[image: DATAFRAME, it has 2892 rows which add up to to around 72 TCA names:]

My goal is to melt (transform) the dataframe into a refined dataframe that looks like the following:

[image: How the new dataframe should look]

This is my code up to now:

```
import glob, pandas as pd



file =  r"C:\Users\jrivera\OneDrive - Accelerate Resources\Documents\Python\maverickAvgTCProductionInput.csv"

dfTotal = pd.DataFrame()

for prd in glob.glob(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(prd)
    dfTotal = pd.concat([dfTotal, df])
dfTotal.shape

dfHDprd = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\jrivera\OneDrive - Accelerate Resources\Documents\Python\maverickAvgTCProductionInput.csv")

id_vars, dct = ["TCA","MONTH",],{}

for x in ["OIL", "GAS"]:
    dct["value_vars_%s" % x] = ["NORM_%s"%x]

dfNew = pd.melt(frame = dfHDprd, id_vars = ["TCA", "MONTHS"], value_vars = ["NORM_OIL_1KFT", "NORM_GAS_1KFT"], var_name= "OIL", var_value = "GAS")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your goal is, from the link it just seems like you want to limit the months between 0-3 and remove some columns. I would suggest explicitly explaining what you need.

pd.melt is used to convert a wide dataframe into a long dataframe by 'melting' columns, with the variable names (NORM_OIL_1KFT, NORM_GAS_1KFT) going into the rows instead of as column headers. I don't think this is what you are looking for.

If you simply want to retain only the columns in your desired dataframe:

```
new_df = dfHDprd[['TCA','MONTH','NORM_OIL_1KFT','NORM_GAS_1KFT']]
new_df.columns = ['TCA','MONTH','OIL','GAS']
```

Melting the dataframe (which probably is not what you are looking to do), you would need to re-define your expression like this to understand the purpose of melting:

```
dfNew = pd.melt(frame = dfHDprd, id_vars = ["TCA", "MONTHS"], value_vars = ["NORM_OIL_1KFT", "NORM_GAS_1KFT"], var_name= "FUEL_TYPE", var_value = "QUANTITY")
```

Where *var_name* is the column header distinguishing between the variables which get melted into the dataframe, and *var_value* is the column header which is the label for the values.

Trivial example (as I can't copy any of your data):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b','c'], 'C1':[1,2,3],'C2':[4,5,6],'C3':[5,6,7]})

>>>

    id  C1  C2  C3
0   a   1   4   5
1   b   2   5   6
2   c   3   6   7

pd.melt(frame=df, id_vars=['id'], value_vars=['C1','C2','C3'], value_name='value', var_name='variable')

>>>
    id  variable value
0   a   C1         1
1   b   C1         2
2   c   C1         3
3   a   C2         4
4   b   C2         5
5   c   C2         6
6   a   C3         5
7   b   C3         6
8   c   C3         7
```